# TFS 2015 "Capacity" tab missing

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template, capacity-planning

I have an "Advanced" license in our TFS 2015. However, the "Capacity" tab is missing when I view the backlog. What else am I missing?

Comment: @jessehouwing I can't seem to find it :(

Comment: Are you looking at the Product Backlog or the Sprint Backlog? Do you have start and end dates defined for your selected sprint? Only when you are on the sprint backlog with defined dates does the capacity tab show up.

Comment: Oh duh! Yes I was fiddling in the Product Backlog. I do see it in Sprint Backlog. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at the Product Backlog or the Sprint Backlog? Do you have start and end dates defined for your selected sprint? Only when you are on the sprint backlog with defined dates does the capacity tab show up.

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue where you must set the Users Access Level to "Basic" or higher, at the Organization level for that user to be able to see the Capacity Tab at all in the Projects.